# Custom list starting new activity?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, listview, android-activity

I have built a customized list item to replace the android's simple list item by inflating each list item. The customized list is working and it consists of an `image view` and a `text view`.

My problem is, when I try to launch a new `activity` after a list item is clicked nothing happens even the app wont crash. So, is there a way to launch an activity using list view???

```
public class activityone extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activitylayout);

        setListAdapter(new MyAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,      R.id.textView1, 
                           getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names)));

    }
    public void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);

            Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);

            if(getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
                Intent intent = new Intent(activityone.this,no1.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
                                   .
                                   .
                                   . 
                                   .

    }

    private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>{

        public MyAdapter(Context context, int resource, int textViewResourceId,
                String[] strings) {
            super(context, textViewResourceId, strings);
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);

            String[] items = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.names);

            ImageView iv = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
            TextView tv = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

            tv.setText(items[position]);


            if(items[position].equals("john")){
                iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.john);
            }
                                   .
                                   .
                                   . 
                                   .

            return row;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is the no1 class

```
public class no1 extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.name_profile);

        CharSequence t1 = "Name: john";
        CharSequence t2 = "Age: 31";
        CharSequence t3 = "Nationality: Saudi";
        CharSequence t4 = "Number: 765646454";

        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.drawable.imageView1);
        TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        TextView tv2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        TextView tv3 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        TextView tv4 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView4);

        iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.john);

        tv1.setText(t1);
        tv2.setText(t2);
        tv3.setText(t3);
        tv4.setText(t4);
    }
}
```

And yes my `activities` are added to the `manifest xml file`.

Thanks for your help.

---

@Vineet Shukla I don't know how to do this i placed a break point but I couldn't debug i am new to eclipse environment could you explain more please

@Divyesh

I edited the code and the app now crashes when i press a list item here is the Logcat trace

```
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to        start activity ComponentInfo{com.abc.act/com.abc.act.no1}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at    android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)

09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at com.abc.act.no1.onCreate(no1.java:31)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: debug and check if you are getting call in: if(getSelectedItemPosition() == 0){
            Intent intent = new Intent(activityone.this,no1.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

Comment: Why didn't you use [SimpleAdapter](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleAdapter.html)?

Comment: @Dan S could you explain more? I don't see a difference!

Comment: someone is null check properly your code and null pointer exception is also give line no. of class where is null value.......

Comment: I didn't understand a thing of what you asked but if you are asking about the no1 class then it shown above i think the null pointer exception is at iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.john);

Comment: Roy nullpointer exception is occured in java or android when someone is null and this exception is also give line number of class that have null value............

Comment: you mean this 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException 09-17 10:10:57.686: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(365): at com.abc.act.no1.onCreate(no1.java:31) 09-17

Comment: null pointer exception is at iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.john);

Comment: ImageView iv = (ImageView) findviewByid(R.id.image);                                                                                      iv.setImageResource(R.drawable.john);                                                                                in your xml file there are imageview id is image................

Comment: Sorry about that no it's not john, my imageView has an id of imageView1

Answer (score 0):

You're not effectively using this API, you should switch to SimpleAdapter because handles more complex List Item layouts and data bindings. Instead of creating intractable branch statements you need to use the underlying data of the list effectively.